# installing dependencies for canvas via brew shows missing package in search path

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using react and trying to install canvas.
First I installed its dependencies via:

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg
```

Then I run:

```
yarn install canvas
```

But I got the following error:

```
Package libpng was not found in the pkg-config search path
```

I tried to add the to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH, but then another shows up missing in the search path and another after that.

If I keep adding them to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH, it ends up with an insane list of packages for that pkg-config search path.

Does anyone have a idea on a solution?